# Street view publish api pose.level won't save

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-streetview-publish

I'm trying to post photo.pose.level on existing photo using Street View Publish API.

When i post GPS, HEADING and LEVEL data, first two (GPS+HEADING) are stored on street view photo, but LEVEL data is lost and won't save (server response is OK).

Here is my POST code that works for HEADING and GPS, i can't figure out where i'm wrong or if i'm missing something.. i think i've done all as described in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/first-app)

```
    $data['pose']['latLngPair']['latitude']=$lat+0;
    $data['pose']['latLngPair']['longitude']=$lon+0;
    $data['pose']['heading']=$heading+0;
    $data['pose']['level']['number']=$level+0;
    $data['pose']['level']['name']='L'.($level+0).'';
    $data_string = json_encode($data);  

    $ch = curl_init('https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo/'.$photo_id.'?key='.$_GOOGLE_API['api_key'].'&updateMask=pose.latLngPair,pose.heading,pose.level');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'authorization: Bearer '.$_GOOGLE_API['access_token'],
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    $json_response=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Try using the API explorer to your tested photos with the [**`photo.get`**](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/get) function, to see if it was properly updated. Are you using [**`photos.list()`**](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/list) when checking if it properly updated?

Comment: I've used [**`photos.batchGet()`**](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photos/batchGet) and [**`photo.get`**](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/get) and was able to see the pose.level I've declared earlier (15 mins ago).

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. How long did you wait? Sometimes it takes up to 24hrs before the data shows up in the getPhoto requests.

Comment: I've sent heading and level info in the same POST about an hour and half ago. Heading came out updated after few seconds but level still not present nor updated. I'm testing on many photos. I'll wait a bit more time